# Scanning other barcodes additional than QR code using Android's Mobile Vision API

Tags: android, barcode, vision-api

Using the barcode detector for mobile vision api, i notices that there are problems scanning formats that are not QR codes.

Im using the latest version of play services (10.2.1), and the barcode generator im using was build like the following:

BarcodeDetector detector = BarcodeDetector.Builder(appContext).build()

Here i have the screenshot for the issue.

[screenshot for scanning barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWgC3.png)

Best regards,

Comment: Have you tried more traditionally sized 2d barcodes rather than the tall one in your screenshot?

Comment: I tried using QR codes and it works, the weird fact here is that BarcodeDetector is not scanning the image using other barcode formats rather than QR codes, such as Data Matrix, PDF-417, AZTEC

Comment: Those other formats do have expected sizes/shapes, I'm wondering if the Vision API checks the 'bounding box' of the suspect barcode to see if it matches a 2d barcode shape.